# How to call Java Servlet from Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, servlets

I've been searching around now for quite a while and can't get any straight answer as to how to call a java servlet from the windows phone 7 API? I've read about 'WebClient' and 'HttpWebRequest' but the implementations seem to differ for normal C# and the windows phone.

The method (or rather empty shell) I have looks like this:

```
public Login(string userName, password){

   string servletUrl = "http://172.12.5.35:8080/SomeService/login?u="+userName+"&p="+password;

   //Somehow to call the servlet>>

}
```

I'm a Java coder, although the syntax is almost identical, I've been thrown in the deep end here coding for the windows phone.

Also maybe worth mentioning that the servlet returns JSON. How does one handle that in C#?

Thanks in advance for any push in the right direction!

---

My Attempt using HttpWebRequest:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(servletUrl);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebRequest)request.BeginGetResponse();
```

But I see that 'BeginGetResponse()' takes 2 arguments namely AsyncCallback & object state. What are these two arguments and what would mine be in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the sample code which makes a web request to get JSON data

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/public_timeline.json", UriKind.Absolute));
```

and the DownloadStringCompleted handler is,

```
void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var jsonResponse= e.Result; // To check whether the json response is obtained or not
    var jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeObject>(e.Result);
}
```

In the above code, `SomeObject` is the Class to which you want to convert the JSON data to.

Additionally, paste your json URL or json Data in [this link](http://json2csharp.com/) to generate the suitable class for you.

Comment: What exactly is 'client_DownloadStringCompleted'? Also in what variable is this Json stored once retrieved?

Comment: What if jsonToCsharp generated 2 classes out of my returned Json?

Comment: JsonConvert is a class from [NewtonSoft.json](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx). And when it generates two classes, take the parent class, which ideally named as RootObject

Comment: Ah I see, and then the very last question (I promise). After I downloaded the json.NET zip file from codeplex, how does one add/incorporate the library in my windows phone project? - Nevermind, got it!

Comment: You would better come here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9092/windows-phone :)

Answer (score 2):

> I've read about 'WebClient' and 'HttpWebRequest' but the implementations seem to differ for normal C# and the windows phone.

Well, it doesn't support the synchronous API, that's all. There are lots of aspects of the WP7 API (and Silverlight in general) which are subsets of the full desktop framework. You need to think asynchronously - you'll *start* making the request, with a callback to fire when you get a response.

Note that this has nothing to do with the implementation of the web server you're talking to. You'd write the same code whether you're talking to a Java servlet, a Rails app, whatever.

> Also maybe worth mentioning that the servlet returns JSON. How does one handle that in C#?

Personally I like [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com) and have used that successfully on Windows Phone 7.

Comment: Thanks for clearing things up a bit Jon. Personally I would rather like to use HttpWebRequest if it's at all possible, if you look at my edited post, you'll see the question I have regarding that...

Comment: @DeanGrobler: The first is a callback. The second is state which is just passed to the callback as a convenience. You'll need to learn about delegates to create the callback. All of this would be better done via tutorials and documentation than via questions on SO though. A search for "WebRequest tutorial silverlight" gives quite a few hits.

Comment: thanks again. I agree, otherwise I'll be sitting here all day asking Q's on it. Just one last question, what do you think of nkchandra's answer? Should work?